# How would I reference exif.js in a Javascript file as I can't use getExif?

Tags: javascript, exif

I am trying to use [exif.js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) on my HTML page, but I don't think I'm referencing the `exif.js` file correctly, as `window.onload = getExif` returns an error saying it's undefined.

I have tried adding `<script src="exif.js type="text/javascript"></script>` to my HTML file and referencing my other file with `<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` as well. It still doesn't seem to be working.

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="exif.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="myimage.png" alt="" id="image">
        <div>
            <span id="metadata"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**:

```
window.onload = getExif;

img = document.getElementById("image")
EXIF.getData(img, function() {
        var allMetaData = EXIF.pretty(this);
        var allMetaDataSpan = document.getElementById("metadata");
        allMetaDataSpan.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(allMetaData,null, "\t");
});
```

The error I got was `Uncaught ReferenceError: getExif is not defined`. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not because everything looks good to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the documentation. `getExif()` was an example function they provided, that is not part of the `exif.js` library.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts my fault, I'm new to javascript. Thank you, I thought getExif was part of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no function named `getExif` defined. It's not something special exported or defined by `exif.js`, but simply a pattern they were following in the documentation examples. I imagine what you were going for is:

```
window.onload = getExif;

function getExif() {
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    EXIF.getData(img, function() {
        var allMetaData = EXIF.pretty(this);
        var allMetaDataSpan = document.getElementById("metadata");
        allMetaDataSpan.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(allMetaData,null, "\t");
    });
}
```